# Divide Euclidean space by surfaces

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, enumerative-combinatorics, curves-and-surfaces, enumerative-geometry

It is well known that $n$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^k$ can divide $\mathbb{R}^k$ into at most $p$ regions where $p$ is
\begin{equation}
1 + n + C^2_n + \cdots + C^k_n
\end{equation}
Is there similar result for $n$ degree $d$ hypersurfaces (i.e. defined by degree $d$ polynomial, not necessarily homogeneous)? Or even more, is there any result for $n$ surfaces with multiple degrees?

Comment: It is  some how  similar to the  first part of the Hilbert 16th problem

Comment: What is $C_n^k$? is it the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: @YCor, yes,it is

Comment: Do you know for a single hypersurface ($n=1$)? For instance $xy=1$ divides the Euclidean plane into 3 components (here $d=2$, $k=2$).

Comment: the result I wrote is for hyperplane not surface

Comment: There is Milnor-Thom theorem bounding the total number of faces of the arrangement. This must be, for example, in Matousek's book Lectures on Discrete Geometry. I do not have it with me now. Thus for a lack of better reference, here is a PDF containing the statement (Thm. 6.2.1). https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/kvg1-tb.pdf Of course, counting all faces is probably an overkill. But at least it provides some bound.